# JWT в cookie в не REST приложении

Tags: веб-программирование, spring, cookie, spring-security, jwt

Я совсем запутался.
Делаю простое веб приложение (не REST) на Spring Boot с использованием Spring Security. Нужно сделать аутентификацию через JWT. Но, как я прочитал, JWT как правило используется для REST приложений, а для не REST приложений я не нашел как отправить JWT токен в ответе, чтобы он добавился в cookie и автоматически отправлялся при каждом запросе клиента. Может я что-то не так понял. Прошу помощи.